# How to download all files linked on a website using wget

Tags: wget

I use the following command to get all PDFs from a website:

```
wget --no-directories --content-disposition --restrict-file-names=nocontrol -e robots=off -A.pdf -r \     url
```

However, this only downloads .pdf files. How can I extend this command to also download .ppt and .doc files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wget`'s `-A` option takes a comma-separated accept LIST, not just a single item.

```
wget --no-directories --content-disposition --restrict-file-names=nocontrol \
    -e robots=off -A.pdf,.ppt,.doc -r url
```

See `man wget` and search for `-A` for more details.